# Adding functionalities to different elements returned by AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have page with dropdown on it for filtering table. With ajax call i target php page where that table is, and i append respond to my index page, actually i used `replaceWith(response)`.
Ok so problem started when i wanted to filter again after i replaced content. I used :

```
$("body").on("click",".show_only", function()
```

Dropdown worked on fresh content, but now there is problem that i can't get other buttons with functionalities to work. I can't just write

```
$("body").on("click",".some-other-class", function(){})
```

Is there a way to solve this? Maybe adding different functions to different elements on same selector

```
$("body").on("click",".show_only .class2 .class3", function1(){}, function2(){}, function3(){})
```

I'm not sure if it even exists. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display different data on each change of your Dropdown list, you should use jquery `.change` function and send to ajax call the value so on server side you will write appropriate code to retrieve the correct data.

```
<select id="drop">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
    </select>


 $("#drop").change(function () {
    var my_value = this.value;
    // AJAX call with my_value as parameter 
});
```

Comment: Above code i posted is only way to add future events. Correct me if i'm wrong, but with your way it didn't work, i tried. I'm sending data-id as parameter, since my options are links. If you didn't understand, i replace whole div with new one from response.

Comment: If you can provide a fiddle with what you are trying to achieve it will be very helpful, because maybe I just don’t understand